# Multiple values files in helmsman dsf file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to know how multiple values files are applied in helmsman.
I have something like below in helmsman dsf file.I want to know whether values-common.yaml will be applied first and then values-dev.yaml so the common values will be overridden by dev values file? Or the order does not matter and it just gets merged .If there is a conflict like commons values has enabled:false,and dev values contains enabled:true,which one will be picked up?

```
prometheus-msteams:
    enabled: true
    group: infra
    namespace: kube-system
    chart: prometheus-msteams/prometheus-msteams
    version: 0.4.3
    valuesFiles:
    - config/prometheus-msteams/values-common.yaml
    - config/prometheus-msteams/values-dev.yaml
    priority: -450
```